# How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value within a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries where one of the values is also a dictionary. In python, I would like to sort the parent list by a value within that nested dictionary.

Example: I need to sort my_list by the value of ['info']['a'] from largest to smallest.

```
my_list = [
    {
        "name" : "name1",
        "info" : {
            "a" : 1,
            "b" : 2,
            "c" : 3
        }
    },
    {
        "name" : "name2",
        "info" : {
            "a" : 3,
            "b" : 2,
            "c" : 1
        }
    },
    {
        "name" : "name3",
        "info" : {
            "a" : 2,
            "b" : 3,
            "c" : 4
        }
    }
]
```

So far the most efficient way I have gotten it to work is by copying the value of ['info']['a'] to a new key/value in the parent dictionary and sorting based on that new value.

```
for d in my_list:   
    d.update({"info_a": d['info']['a']})

sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=itemgetter('info_a'), reverse=True)
```

Another way I got it to work was creating a whole new list of dictionaries from certain keys, sorting that, then using that to add dictionaries all one by one into a new list. This seems unnecessarily complicated and inefficient.

```
temp_list = []
sorted_list = []

for d in my_list:
    entry = {}
    entry.update({"name" : d['name'],
                    "info_a" : d['info']['a']})
    temp_list.append(entry)

for temp_d in sorted(temp_list, key=itemgetter('a'), reverse = True):
    for d in my_list:
        if temp_d['name'] == d['name']:
            sorted_list.append(d)
```

Surely there is some way to sort by the nested value without having to make new objects ?

Comment: Wouldn't `output = sorted(my_list, key=lambda dct: dct['info']['a'], reverse=True)` be fine?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own `key` – no big deal:

```
sorted_list = sorted(my_list, key=lambda val: val["info"]["a"], reverse=True)
```